# Frigidaire washing machine's agitator does not spin, but the drum spins. What could be the issue?

Tags: repair, appliances, washing-machine

Have a Frigidaire fex831fs4 washer and dryer combo where washer has following symptoms:

1. when washing machine is off, the agitator can be freely turned by hand both directions.
2. when washing machine is on, the agitator does not agitate, but the drum does spin.

I found that common cause for these symptoms (at least for other brand washers) is that agitator dogs are worn.

However, on [my washer parts list](https://www.partswarehouse.com/Frigidaire-FEX831FS4-Washer-Dryer-Combo-s/70206.htm), I can't find such part.

**My questions:**

1. Do Frigidaire washers have agitator dogs at all?
2. If not, then is the agitation controlled by transmission for my Frigidaire washer?

Answer (score 1):

The "agitator dogs" are protrusions on the agitator that couple it to its drive shaft.

Often one side of such a coupling is made of plastic that self destructs when it gets jammed to avoid stalling and damaging the motor. (That it creates planned obsolescence is just a bonus).

So the part you need is either a new agitator or a new transmission.

Comment: Not sure I follow what you are saying... 1) by saying that I "need to change transmission or agitator" are you implying that my washer does not have those plastic agitator dogs? 2) with "planned obsolescence" are you suggesting that my washer has reached end of life and probably will need to be rebuild completely because parts were designed to last this long (if I replace just the agitator dogs, then probably something else will soon fail)?

Comment: No I'm saying that those dogs ate part of either the agitator itself or the shaft that it connects to.

Answer (score 0):

[image]
These are the agitator dogs @ratchet freak indicated, you can probably  locate them online for your model. There is a single bolt from above holding the agitator on.  You might need a long extension socket.  You can likely find a short help youtube video searching "agitator repair fridgadare washing machine"